# How to use case statement in SQLServer Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

I have a Stored procedure like:

```
Create  PROCEDURE GetValidationData(
@ContextKey INT  --Input parameter ,  Key to execute Statement 
)AS
BEGIN
if (@ContextKey = 1) 
begin 
 Select * from table A......
end
if (@ContextKey = 2) 
begin
 Some another select statement ......
end
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
like n
END
```

`@ContextKey` is a parameter which execute proper Select Statement

Now I want to convert all code in CASE WHEN THEN statement how can i do this?
on the basis of `@ContextKey`

Comment: If statement is a better choice if the purpose was to choose the right select query based on a condition.

Comment: If the two `SELECT` statements are very different form each other, you are better off with `IF...ELSE`. Only one code block will be executed anyway.

Comment: `CASE WHEN` in TSQL is an EXPRESSION, not a statement!  Each then or else can be a complicated nested expression, but ends up as a scalar value.

Comment: Can you provide **why** you want to do this? your current code is good enough

Comment: Like the others say - why do this? I also note that the 'CASE' statement won't *necessarily* be semantically identical to the original: if one of your code blocks modifies the value of @ContextKey, then it's possible more than one code block will end up being executed with your current code. The 'CASE' version would remove that possibility.

Comment: I agree with all of you guys. but the thing is that we have more than 150 contextkey in our code. while executing 150th key it checks 149 key in if else statement which takes more execution time.
if there is any other option please let me suggest.
Thanks!

Comment: I have anoher reason why you would not want to do this.  You can not define a "default" case in which you can throw an error for instance...  What if you gradually want to maintain this, but a new context is added, and you forget to define it -> you want the script to send a message "context id not implemented yet", so you know you have to fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
Create  PROCEDURE GetValidationData(
@ContextKey INT  --Input parameter ,  Key to execute Statement 
)AS
BEGIN
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
select @sql = case @ContextKey 
                    when 1 then 'Select * from table A'
                    when 2 then 'Select another select statement'
                    when number then 'Select other '
                end
execute(@sql)

END
```

Comment: While your answer is correct and will result in the correct output as described by the OP, this is not the correct way to go. If OP is asking for something which is fundamentally wrong and should not be implemented, it is our duty to mention the best way forward. For example, If you had to maintain this code which version would you prefer? yours or the original version in the question.

Comment: I am not sure why he required this code. If I am to choose the best of these two then definitely I will check other parameters which are yet to be answered  by the OP why I need case when he is comfortable with if else. What other select statement contain. Reason why I posted my answer is to the best of my knowledge OP has just started learning SQL and he wants to explore the possibilities. Anyway he was enough said in the comment section prior to my answer that it is better to stay with if else.

Comment: Well its not really a matter of comfort. 1. `CASE` is not meant to be used as a control flow for statements, `IF` is. 2. Your implementation uses [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) which opens up a can of worms if used incorrectly.

Comment: I am really happy to know why case shouldn't be used as a control flow statement. I am aware of msdn notes but I haven't found the reason why is it so. Coming to dynamic sql it is clear in the notes itself  "Of course, in a T-SQL procedure where the value is passed as an int parameter there is no risk".

Comment: agree with azar. really need a case statement in T-SQL

Comment: The [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) _expression_ is not a _statement_. That limits its usefulness for control of flow.